# How do channels work with inout gates?

Tags: omnet++

First of all I know that inout gates are composed of an input and output gates stuck together. Which leads me to the following questions

- When a channel is assigned to a connection between two inout gates in NED, do the input and output gate share the channel, or are two different channels created?
- Say, you had a vector of inout gates, if you used getBaseId, to get the base id of the gates in the vector. if you iterated through the vector would the gate you get using each increment on the base id be an inout gate, or an input/output gate?

What I am trying to do is, dynamically add inout gates to a gate vector, as well as dynamically modify the properties of channels of previous inout gates which are part of a vector. 
I recently started using Omnetpp, and have read the manual and a lot of things on the Internet, but I couldn't find an answer to these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The two gates connect to two independent channel objects
- There is no such thing as a 'vector of inout gate'. There are two separate gate vectors. One is with the name 'gatename$i' the other is with 'gatename$o' each one is a separate gate vector. (with possibly differet baseIds). Think the

`mod1.gateA[2] <--> mod2.gateB[5]`

as a shorthand for

```
mod1.gateA$o[2] --> mod2.gateB$i[5]    
mod1.gateA$i[2] <-- mod2.gateB$o[5]
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think your question is answered, you should accept it so other people will benefit too in the future, in case they have the same problem.

Comment: But the second answer leads to the question of how do you access the base id of each vector from c++; would it be something like  `int baseId = gateBaseId("out$i");`  @Rudi

Comment: That' why you should not ask two questions in a single post (as one question leads to an other and you will never now which is answered and which is not). As for your question: gate("out$i")->getBaseId()